# (Unity) How do i modify a velocity to be in relation to a certain direction as opposed to the world axis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I am programming a 3D third person game. I have the player's controls almost fully figured out, however the only thing that is not how i would like it is the movement.
The way the movement works at the moment is that if i tilt the analog stick or WASD i move in that direction in relation to the world axis. This is not what i want, as when i spin the cinemachine camera around the character still moves in relation to the world axis, which means i could be looking backwards from my point of view, but the character still moves along the negative Z axis
I know exactly whay i want to happen, just i dont know how to implement it in c#:

- I want to get the forward facing direction of the active camera (It usually looks something like (1, 0, -1) or something when i print it with cam.transform.forward)
- I want to get the raw velocity that should be implemented upon the character
- I want to modify this velocity so that the zero/forwards value is the way the camera is facing, and the direction of movement velocity is added to this direction to get the way the character should move

Here is an example of what is happening, if i made no sense there at all:

- My character is facing into the positive X axis witht the camera directly behind him. What i want to happen is, if i hit right, him to walk into a negative Z direction, since that is, from the camera's persepctive, right from where it is facing. Instead what happens is that character keeps walking towards positive X because, in relation to the world's forwards axis of positive Z, positive X is right... Might not make sense either but theres something if youre struggling to visualise it

Here is the relevant code so far:

```
//SpeedMod is a floating point value that changes the speed the character is moving
//rb is the character' rigidbody
//Movement smothing is a floating point value that adjusts how much the character leans into its velocity


targetVelocity = new Vector3(
                Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speedMod * Time.fixedDeltaTime,
                rb.velocity.y,
                Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speedMod * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
rb.velocity = Vector3.Lerp(rb.velocity, targetVelocity, movementSmoothing);

//This bit sorts out the rotation of the character, so isnt related to velocity
if (rb.velocity.magnitude > 0.001f)
{
targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical")), Vector3.up);
transform.rotation =
                    Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") == 0 && Input.GetAxis("Vertical") == 0
                    ?
                    transform.rotation
                    :
                    Quaternion.Lerp(
                        transform.rotation,
                        targetRotation,
                        rotationSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
}
```

This is all inside a fixed upate function
Thanks for reading through all that. Id really like help on this, as ive been struggling with it for a good week

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `transform`.  It already has the directions for you.
eg:

```
transform.up;
transform.right;
transform.forward;
```

If you need arbitrary directions, then:

```
var inWorldSpace = transform.TransformDirection( objectSpaceVector );
var inObjectSpace = transform.InverseTransformDirection( worldSpaceVector);
```

Comment: Hi. I'm not sure you understand; i want the direction the camera is facing to be the forwards direction, and then have the direction of the velocity to be determined by the direction of the analog stick in relation to camera.transform.forward. When i am not moving, this will give me the ability to pan around the character, like Assassins creed or zelda: breath of the wild. I will try using these and feedback though! :D

Answer (score 1):

What i ended up doing, for those of you who are interested, is using a lookrotation with the cam.forward & cam.up directions, then multiplying this by the velocity i had calculated to get that velocity relative to the camera's direction. Now i have an assassin's creed style camera that snaps behind the player when moving forward, but lets me freespin the camera when standing still!

```
 if (isGrounded)
            {
                //Handle the actual movement & rotation
                targetVelocity = Quaternion.LookRotation(cam.transform.forward, cam.transform.up) * new Vector3(
                    Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speedMod,
                    rb.velocity.y,
                    Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speedMod);

                rb.velocity = Vector3.Lerp(rb.velocity, targetVelocity, movementSmoothing);
            }

            if (rb.velocity.magnitude > 0.001f)
            {
                targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetVelocity.normalized, Vector3.up);

                transform.rotation = new Quaternion(
                    transform.rotation.x,
                    Quaternion.Lerp(
                        transform.rotation,
                        targetRotation,
                        rotationSpeed).y,
                        transform.rotation.z,
                        transform.rotation.w);
            }
```